# Install a software: launching a command before the installation and another one after it

Tags: installation, nsis

I am trying to create an installation package with NSIS, and I need to launch a command before the installation and another one after it.

This is what I tried without success:

```
Name "MyProgram"
OutFile "MyInstall.exe"
InstallDir "$PROGRAMFILE\MyProgram"

Function .onInit
    !system vs_redist.x64.exe
FunctionEnd

Section "My Program"
    SetOutPath $INSTDIR
    File /r "xamp\*.*"
    File "start.bat"
    File "readme.txt"
SectionEnd

Function .onInstSuccess
    !system xampp/setup_xampp.bat
FunctionEnd
```

It seems it does not call the two functions

Answer (score 1):

`!system` executes external commands at compile-time. Use `ExecWait` to execute something at run-time:

```
Function .onInit
InitPluginsDir ; Create $pluginsdir temp folder
File "/oname=$Pluginsdir\myapp.exe" "c:\myfiles\myapp.exe"
ExecWait '"$Pluginsdir\myapp.exe" /param1 "par am 2" /param3' $0
MessageBox mb_ok "Returned $0"
FunctionEnd
```

Comment: It extracts a .exe to a temporary location and then executes it (and waiting for it to finish). Read the help file for a description of each command if you are unsure.

Comment: I do not understand what I can use for my purpose.

Comment: You said you wanted to launch a command before the installation and this code does that. Just change `myapp.exe` and the launch parameters to whatever you need.